# Writing into a variable without knowing the total size in advance

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

I need to modify an existing function, which is creating a file according to the configuration of the system. The total size of the created file is not known in advance. Thus, the original function simply creates a file and dumps everything into it. It even keeps some offsets in memory and updates the file during the process.

I am not allowed to create a file on the disk. I need to keep everything in one single variable. However, I don't know the total size in advance.

Can you suggest me a data structure for this case?

Comment: `if(!I_have_memory_constraints())`

Comment: `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` or `std::string`

Comment: for non binary you can use `std::ostringstream`, for binary you can use `std::vector<std::uint8_t>`

Answer (score 1):

Just to correct @Raxvan's answer.  You can write binary to a std::stringstream.  For example if you want to read and write to a stringstream declare it as:

```
std::stringstream buffer(std::iostream::in | std::iostream::out | std::iostream::binary);
```

If you want to write binary data to it:

```
int integer = 1234;
buffer.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&integer), sizeof(int));
```

If you want to read from it later:

```
int integer = 0;
buffer.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&integer), sizeof(int));
```

You don't need to specify the length beforehand.  If you need the length afterwards, you can use something like:

```
buffer.str().size();
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: can I keep the offset of a position, come back to it and edit the data at that position?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for sure.
There are two pointers on the data buffer.  A put and a get pointer.  So easiest way to explain it is to say that the put is for writing and the get is for reading.
So finding the position of the put pointer can be done like this:

Try something like this:

```
//Get the offset where the write pointer is..
std::streamoff offset = buffer.tellp();
//Write 'dummy' value
buffer.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&integer), sizeof(int));
.
.
.
(do other writing)
.
.
.
//Scroll to offset (from start)
buffer.seekp(offset);
//Write real value
buffer.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&integer), sizeof(int));
```

Okay, so that is if you want to scroll to an offset from the start.
If you want to scroll from you current position look at things like:

```
buffer.seekp(offset, std::ios_base::cur);
```